# I have integrated razor pay in my app for premium templates. I need make app live on play store but not able understand in-app prodcuts flow

Tags: android, google-play-services

I went to monetize-> in-app products and got option to upload app in closed testing but I am not able to get option of product ID or option create product. I have not integrated google billing in app, I have just integrated razor pay. Can any explain whole process of uploading app with in-app on playstore.

I tried uploading app in in-app products but app went live in closed testing.